# Remove all submit listeners

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to remove all possibility of submitting a form in a chrome extension (writing it for my own use).  I've tried `( ":submit" ).each().die()`.  But something about that doesn't feel proper (nor run).

I've also tried

```
$('button').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `submit` event is raised by the `form` element, not the `button`. Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that works.  I'd also like to prevent buttons from triggering events too, would that also be simple?

Comment: $('button').prop('disabled', true);

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For preventing form to submit, Better Way is to return false when form submit. you can do that by the following code :

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
return false;
});
```

Now form will not be submitted. 
Hope it helps.
Thank you.

Comment: Define _"Better Way"_. See [this article](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) for the differences.

Comment: Actually `return false` is no *better*, nor is it worse. Returning false is in effect the same as using both `preventDefault()` *and* `stopPropagation()`. If that's what you want, great. If not, then it will cause you problems.